# How to convert string read in by search bar to an object -- JSON / usernames

Tags: javascript, html, json, object

Im new to stack overflow so pls be patient with me.

JSON:

```
{"mcokzoo":{"id":48182210,"name":"mcokzoo","profileIconId":682,"summonerLevel":30,"revisionDate":1413774230000}}
```

Lets say I have the json above.  I changed the data and removed stuff that didn't matter.  I want the user to input their username into the search bar and then use that to find their id.

```
function getSummonerId(username)
{
    url = summonerURL+"/by-name/" + username + key;
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", url, false );
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    var jsonText = xmlHttp.responseText;
    var summonerData = JSON.parse(jsonText);
    //alert(jsonText)

    return summonerData.(This is the part i have not clue)         

}
```

Idk what to put in the above spot.  I can't put the string name and I can seem to figure out how to put a variable name their correctly w/o hard coding.  Any suggestions?

### EDIT

I can't get it to work when i do window[variableName] also I read I wasn't suppose to use eval - also not working.  Also I'm not using jquery which would also make the problem different

Comment: Is there a form you are using? The fields would have ids/names.

Comment: The json is erroneous... Give the correct JSON and also what is "jetstream" here? is this what you want to search..??

Comment: the "jetstream" is the username that i have collected from the field

Comment: I also haven't done the form yet 'Code Whisperer' I just thought once I got this working it would be as simple as adding text field and button to submit data